# How to use Thread.Sleep in WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

In a WPF application VS 2010, I basically need to print a document and check for errors after few seconds it start to print.

At the moment I am using `Thread.Sleep(2000)` but it does not work. The `try` code I believe is running in the UI thread.

Any idea how to fix it? Or better approach?

In this specific case I do not care if the UI Thread is blocked for few seconds.

```
try
{
    printer = new Printer();
    printer.PrintTicket(dataAdv);
    // check eventual problem during printing like paper jamp
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    if (monitorPrinter.IsPrinterReady() == false)
    {
        isPrinterReady = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Problem during the printing!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yuck! Don't sleep for two seconds in your UI thread - your users won't appreciate it. Create a worker thread to do the printing and use a callback to get the result.

Comment: Can you define what's not working about it, too? (see previous comment for better approach)

Comment: Does the API not have error events? What if the printer is simply busy?

Comment: Basically it is for a kiosk app. Only a User can print a document at a time. Only after printing complete you can print another document.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to my problem thanks all for pointing me out in the right direction.

```
try
{
   printer = new Printer();
   printer.PrintTicket(dataAdv);

   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
   dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
   dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
   dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (monitorPrinter.IsPrinterReady() == false)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("SOME PROBLEM WHEN PRINTING!");
   }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, if your application is a Windows Forms application, you can use System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead. This is optimized for a Windows Forms application.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx